# Check/uncheck input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

If you click on `buton` it opens 3 checkbox (one that selects it all and two subinputs).

What I'm trying to do is that if the user clicks for example on `Centro de dia` the input remains checked and the other (`buton` in this case) gets unchecked. If the user clicks on `buton` the other gets unchecked, and if the user clicks on Check/uncheck all it obviously checks all or uncheck them all.

But right now if I click on one of the subinputs, it checks/unchecks but **doesn't affect the other one.**

This is the code i'm using:

```
    $check_all = $('<label></label>')
        .text(GeoMashup.opts.check_all_label)
        .prop('for', 'gm-' + taxonomy + '-check-all')
        .prepend(
            $('<input type="checkbox" />').prop('id', 'gm-' + taxonomy + '-check-all')
            .prop('checked', (default_off ? false : 'checked'))
            .change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $legend.find('input.gm-' + taxonomy + '-checkbox:not(:checked)').click();
                } else {
                    $legend.find('input.gm-' + taxonomy + '-checkbox:checked').click();
                }
            })
```

Any ideas how to make it work that way?

Comment: You should use prop (http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of setting the attribute with jQuery

Comment: @codek: Which Jquery version you used?

Comment: @IshanJain i'm using 1.10.2 version

Comment: @codek: you should use .prop() instead of using .attr(). To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Changed to it right now, it does the same problem

Comment: I feel like something is missing... Is there any event handler that causes this chunk of code to run?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .prop() instead of .attr() if using Jquery 1.6 and above.